# Where did the user agent field go in my Chrome DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Suddenly, I no longer see the "UA" field in my Chrome DevTools.

[image: No UA field in Chrome]

It should be where the "Configure throttling" text is in the above image. Not sure if I inadvertently edited a setting or if this is a recent update, but I can't seem to figure out how to get this back. Help?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There seems to be a lot of development happening on Device Mode. (E.g. if you try it out in Chrome Canary it looks very different.)

For now, you can customize the user agent like this:

1. Open the Console Drawer

[image]

2. Select "Network Conditions" in the dropdown in the console section.

[image]

3. Uncheck "Select Automatically", Select "custom user agent"

[image]

Comment: Thanks, thought I was going crazy!

Answer (score 4):

With Chrome Version **75.0.3770.100 (Windows)** you can find it as below

1. Open **Developer Tools** and go to **Network conditions** setting

[image: Image 1]

2. Open **Network conditions**. There you will find the **User agent** option set to Select automatically by default. Uncheck it to get a list of supported user agents.

You can also provide your custom user agent by selecting the **Custom** option from the list.

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 2):

Source: [Official Documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/override-user-agent)

1. Press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Windows, Linux, Chrome OS) to open the Command Menu.
2. Type **network conditions**, select **Show Network conditions**, and press Enter to open the Network conditions tab.
3. In the User agent section disable the **Select automatically** checkbox.
4. Select a user agent string from the list, or enter your own custom string.